# return a class with empty values

Tags: c#

I have the following code.
If there is no WType is blank, I like to return an empty class with empty strings for Key and Value. I am getting an error that a ";" is expected.

The return type needs to be:

```
IEnumerable<WportType>
```

Here is the code:

```
if (wType == "Riconda")
{
    return dbContext.data_LookupValues
       .Where(w => w.Category == "WLoc")
       .OrderBy(w => w.SortId)
       .Select(a => new WportType
       {
           Key = a.Key,
           Value = a.Value
       });

}
else 
{
    return  WportType
       {
           Key = "",
           Value = ""
       }; 
}
```

Comment: What is the return type of this method? Even if you fix the syntax error, in one part, you're trying to return an `IQueryable<WportType>` and in the other a `WportType`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return new WportType // you missed new keyword also
   {
       Key = "",
       Value = ""
   }; // and ; here
```

But that is not single problem in your code. *If* part returns `IEnumerable<WportType>` and *else* part returns simple `WportType`. You should either select single object from database or create collection with default value in *else* part:

```
if (wType == "Riconda")
{
    return dbContext.data_LookupValues
       .Where(w => w.Category == "WLoc")
       .OrderBy(w => w.SortId)
       .Select(a => new WportType {
           Key = a.Key,
           Value = a.Value
       }); // or use something like FirstOrDefault() here

}
else 
{
    return new List<WportType> {
         new WportType { Key = "", Value = "" }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears your method returns an `IEnumerable<WportType>`. You are attempting to return a single item. You need to wrap this within a collection:

Like below:

```
    if (wType == "Riconda")
    {
        return dbContext.data_LookupValues
           .Where(w => w.Category == "WLoc")
           .OrderBy(w => w.SortId)
           .Select(a => new WportType
           {
               Key = a.Key,
               Value = a.Value
           });

    }
    else 
    {
        return new[] { new WportType { Key = "", Value = "" } };
    }
```

Comment: You'll probably need to wrap the second one in a `new[] { .. }`, because the first part returns a enumerable/queryable of that type of item.

Comment: Not correct - Enumerable.Empty is not same as WportType with default values

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy You've absolutely correct. I've added the second way of doing that in my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
return dbContext.data_LookupValues
           .Where(w => w.Category == "WLoc")
           .OrderBy(w => w.SortId)
           .Select(a => new WportType
           {
               Key = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(wType) ? a.Key : "",
               Value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(wType) ? a.Value : ""
           });
```

Judging from your question, I'm not exactly sure what your end goal is, but this method will preserve the length of your original query and just set the values of your WportType with "" when your wType is null or empty.